# Cells disappear when i change the UITableView background

Tags: ios, uitableview, background

```
tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor
tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone

background = UIImageView.alloc.initWithImage( UIImage.imageNamed "soft.png" )
tableView.addSubview( background )
tableView.sendSubviewToBack( background )
```

This is what I'm using to change the background of my table view (grouped style). When I do it this way, the section titles remain, but the table view cells all disappear... What the heck is going on? How can I fix this?

Also, when I scroll I can see black bounce in and out of the screen, which is ugly. This is not my primary problem, but I feel like a solution to the first problem may also fix this one...

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add a subview to get a background image. UITableView already has a backgroundView property that you can just set.

```
UIImageView *background = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"whatever.png"]];
self.tableView.backGroundView = background;
```

Comment: You fixed both issues! Hoorah!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
tableView.addSubview( background );
tableView.sendSubviewToBack( background );
```

use

```
[tableView setBackgroundView:background];
```

Comment: I'm surprised anything at all happens when he's doing what he's doing. That is not proper syntax for function calls in Obj-C and should normally throw some compiler errors.

Comment: I agree, also there are no `;` so I'm thinking he just typed all of that on the spot, it isn't a copy paste from an app.

Comment: Great, guy above gives the same answer, but I get no cred, sigh.

Comment: rep for almost being first and in motion syntax